# Override default includePath for intelliSense in vscode C/C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, libc

I am trying to configure vscode intellisense for a C project where I have a custom compiler which is using his "own" implementation of the standard lib (optimized for the targeted processor).

I can succesfully include project libraries, e.g. `#include <gpio.h>` refers to the correct specific implementation of the project.

But in the case of let's say `#include <string.h>` intellisense is pointing to my standard windows install (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\string.h) and not to the desired one who should be in my case in C:/MWLite/MetaWare/arc/libs/inc/string.h

I included the path in c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "name": "arc",
    "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "C:/MWLite/MetaWare/arc/**"
    ],
    "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE"
    ],
    "compilerPath": "C:/MWLite/MetaWare/arc/bin/gmake.exe",
    "cStandard": "c11",
    "cppStandard": "c++17",
    "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
}
```

How can I "force" intellisense to look first in the specified path for libc?

Comment: why is `gmake` your compiler path? If you properly set `compilerPath` to your compiler vscode should figure out the actual include path from your compiler without the need of `includePath` (according to the docs anyway).

Comment: also if you are targeting arduino, take a look over https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/ide/vscode.html

Comment: @bolov yea I saw that but thanks. I already added gmake path to my env variables but vscode is not recognizing it so I added it in compilerPath (where it seems to be ok). But the issue is not with the compiler (I compile from a terminal and will probably use a task in the future), it seems to be with intellisense. As for Arduino sadly it is not, it is really some custom controller using an arc proc :) and I wanted to understand the full toolchain and configure vscode in a good way

Comment: my point was that `gmake` is not the compiler (it is a build system). If you put the real compiler in `compilerPath` (something like `gcc-my-custom-controller-build`) and remove `includePath` then vscode should be able to get the real include paths that the compiler uses (assuming it accepts gcc compatible arguments). Anyway it's just speculation from my part. Worth trying though.